Does Stripe paymentelement shows different payment options for clientsecret created using paymentIntent and setupIntent
I have 2 flows regarding payment:

Charge a customer using payment element created from paymentIntent.
I have another flow where I only accept payment methods from a customer using setupIntent.

In this first flow I follow below steps:

Create a paymentIntent using customerId and amount

const paymentIntent = await stripeKey.paymentIntents.create({
            customer: customerId,
            setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
            amount: amount,
            currency: 'usd',
            metadata : {
                tenantId :  tenantId,
                customerId : customerId,
                transaction_from : transaction_from,
            },
             automatic_payment_methods: {
                enabled: true,
                allow_redirects: 'always'
             }
        });


Use paymentIntent secret key to show paymentelement

      const appearance = {
        theme: 'stripe',
          };

      const options = {
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        appearance,
      };

      elements = stripe.elements(options);
      paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
      paymentElement.mount("#payment");  


This shows payment element as below:

Payment element created using paymentIntent
In this second flow I follow below steps:

Create a setupIntent

const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({

      customer: customerId,
      metadata: {clientid : tenantId},

        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
            allow_redirects: 'always'
        }
    });


Use setupIntent secret key to show paymentelement

      const appearance = {
          theme: 'stripe',
        };
    
        const options = {
          clientSecret: setupIntent.client_secret,
          appearance,
        };
        
    
        elements = stripe.elements(options);
    
        const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
    
        paymentElement.mount("#paymentMethod"); 


This shows payment element as below:

payment element created using setupIntent
The problem here is that both payment elements are not showing the same payment methods, which results in inconsistency. What additional steps do I need to take to show the same payment methods on both payment elements?

This behavior is expected, as some payment methods are designated for Payment usage and not for Setup usage. For instance, certain options like "Buy Now Pay Later" payment methods (e.g. Klarna) might not be available for Setup usage.

